# Is there a way to prevent author change when editor/administrator edits a post?

Tags: admin, author, quick-edit

As an administrator when I change or edit a post of an author (for example add a category through quick edit) the author of the post changes. We do not want this to happen. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both, quick edit and the regular post edit screen, offer an author field. Just take care to set the correct author when you edit something.

[image]

To see this field you have to enable it in the screen option in the upper right corner:

[image]

Comment: i don't see author field, neither in edit nor in quick edit... :( is this bound to a prop or feature.

Comment: Yes, you need the capability [`edit_others_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_others_posts). You should add this capability to the person who is responsible for edits.

Comment: thank you for your answer and the comments but i have the administrator role (which has that capability naturally i think)... but still can't see.

Comment: @spinodal You may need to enable the field first. See my update.

Comment: i found out what is going wrong after your update. although I enabled everything in the screen options i did not see the author update combo. then I realize what is the source of the problem. ths problem was "co-authors" plugin... if you have that plugin you cannot edit the author through edit or quickedit

Comment: @spinodal Interesting and good to know. Tell the plugin author about the problem. I’m sure he wants to find a way to work around this.