# Find the user who initially created the post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have created the post by user (A), later I changed the user of the post to (B),
Now I want to find out who initially created the post i.e. user (A) who originally created it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, you can take a look into [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/feature-request-retain-original-post-author/) link or [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78014/post-author-is-changed-to-admin-after-his-post-is-modified-by-admin) if you want to track the publisher of a post.

Comment: Thanks Jack for the reply. But this does not give me the existing post old author name/id..any more suggestion?

Comment: I'm because the old authors are overwritten. You can use this feature for future posts.

Comment: sorry Jack I am not getting what he explained any other solution which could be done in functions.php file?

Comment: You can try what @fergbrain explained in his answer, if you haven't deleted the revisions you might be able to retrieve the data. If it didn't help, then i will post an answer for further use.

Comment: Jack please give another solution, which I can store while creating the post itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52253/discussion-between-1991wp-and-jack-johansson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to your issue.

**1-** Getting the original author inside a loop

To retrieve the original author of a post inside a loop, you can use `get_the_author();` to get the username of the author or `$post->post_author();` to get his/her user id. If you wish to get the revisor's username or id, you can use `the_modified_author();` or `get_the_modified_author();`.

**2-** In the back-end

If you want to have this result in the back-end (view the original author in the admin panel), you can use the following plugin made specifically for this purpose.

[Published By](https://wordpress.org/plugins/published-by/) plugin made by Scott reilly

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: I think this could be achieved without plugin too

Comment: Yes for sure, but plugin is the easiest way, and needs no extra coding.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to sleuth through the mySQL database. Every change to a post is saved. Run the following query using phpMyAdmin (or your mySQL tool of choice):
`SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename, wp_posts.post_title FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_users ON wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID WHERE post_parent = 1234`

`1234` is the current post_id of the post you want to find.

This will display the user id, user nicename, and title of the post for the *prior* revisions.

Comment: Sorry fergbrain this is not helping out..

Comment: Can you be more specific?